# jinja2 exception in pyramid - fatal error

Tags: python, jinja2, pyramid

Any jinja2 exception is not caught and propagates to top resulting in fatal error shown by waitress. Any thoughts how to fix this? I would like it to be caught be debug toolbar.

Pyramid 1.5.7
pyramid-debugtoolbar
pyramid_jinja2
Tried on python 3.4 and 3.5

Comment: Please share the whole traceback

Comment: https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_debugtoolbar/issues/242

Comment: There is a possible fix, unfortunately the issue is not easy to replicate (certain characters/character set), please give this a shot: https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_debugtoolbar/pull/244 and see if that fixes the issue.